# Swift : core data crashed when getting persistentStoreCoordinator after applicationWillTerminate

Tags: ios, core-data, crash

We updated our app to a new version.

There was a new function added to the new version and we added a new coredata table for that function.

After app was released, an error continued without no answer.
Would somebody met the same error or same problem and solved this error?

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x000000018981f014 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x0000000189793400 abort + 140
2   [AppName]                           0x00000001002d0c58 AppDelegate.(persistentStoreCoordinator.getter).(closure #1) (AppDelegate.swift:318)
3   [AppName]                           0x00000001002c7dec AppDelegate.persistentStoreCoordinator.getter (AppDelegate.swift:334)
4   [AppName]                           0x00000001002d0cbc AppDelegate.(managedObjectContext.getter).(closure #1) (AppDelegate.swift:338)
5   [AppName]                           0x00000001002c8054 AppDelegate.managedObjectContext.getter (AppDelegate.swift:342)
6   [AppName]                           0x00000001002c8198 AppDelegate.saveContext() (AppDelegate.swift:347)
7   [AppName]                           0x00000001002c7780 AppDelegate.applicationWillTerminate() (AppDelegate.swift:295)
8   [AppName]                           0x00000001002c77d8 @objc AppDelegate.applicationWillTerminate() (AppDelegate.swift:0)
9   UIKit                               0x0000000190792704 <redacted> + 244
10  UIKit                               0x00000001909947cc <redacted> + 792
11  UIKit                               0x0000000190997fdc <redacted> + 292
12  UIKit                               0x0000000190989d50 <redacted> + 560
13  UIKit                               0x00000001906f90b4 <redacted> + 168
14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018a7fe0c0 <redacted> + 32
15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018a7fbcf0 <redacted> + 372
16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018a7fc180 <redacted> + 1024
17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018a72a2b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
18  GraphicsServices                    0x000000018c1de198 GSEventRunModal + 180
19  UIKit                               0x00000001907717fc <redacted> + 684
20  UIKit                               0x000000019076c534 UIApplicationMain + 208
21  [AppName]                           0x00000001002d1a94 main (AppDelegate.swift:17)
22  ???                                 0x000000018970d5b8 0x0 + 0
```

Comment: Addition of new field, entity in Core Data invalidate your earlier Core data model which can leads to crash always. if you delete app and reinstall it should work.

Comment: That stack trace shows that the app crashes while trying to save changes. There's no other useful information. Is that the only time you try to save changes? What happens if you save at some other time? And what error message(s) do you get besides the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should post the erronious code, e.g. the getters in the AppDelegate (line numbers see stack trace).

In general, waiting until the application is terminated can take a very long time (because iOS tries to keep them alive,  since iOS 4 i think). You could tranfer the logic into `applicationDidEnterBackground`, but I think this is also error prone because this will not be called if the app crashes somehow.

You should save the context as often as possible (but not more often :-), e.g. every time a view controller gets dismissed or so.